# How to compare elements of one array in other js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays. One start from 1st date to 31st date.
Other array contains dates only.

I want to compare the dates from other array to 1st one.

The code is:

```
{console.log(publicHolidays, '=================')}
            {
                daysNumber.map((name, index) => (
                    <TableCell align="right" key={`mi-${index}`}>{days[this.getDayOfWeek(name)]}</TableCell>
                ))
            }
```

publicHolidays: `["2020-05-02","2020-05-06","2020-05-21"]`

daysNumber:

```
[
  "2020-05-01",
  "2020-05-02",
  "2020-05-03",
  "2020-05-04",
  "2020-05-05",
  "2020-05-06",
  "2020-05-07",
  "2020-05-08",
  "2020-05-09",
  "2020-05-10",
  "2020-05-11",
  "2020-05-12",
  "2020-05-13",
  "2020-05-14",
  "2020-05-15",
  "2020-05-16",
  "2020-05-17",
  "2020-05-18",
  "2020-05-19",
  "2020-05-20",
  "2020-05-21",
  "2020-05-22",
  "2020-05-23",
  "2020-05-24",
  "2020-05-25",
  "2020-05-26",
  "2020-05-27",
  "2020-05-28",
  "2020-05-29",
  "2020-05-30",
  "2020-05-31"
]
```

If date from public holiday found and that date is saturday or sunday in daysNumber then do some stuff is my requirement here.

Like change the color of that date in DaysNumber loop.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Here you can use indexOf

Comment: Array includes()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const publicHolidays = ["2020-05-02", "2020-05-06", "2020-05-21"]
const daysNumber = [ "2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-03", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-09", "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-14", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-16", "2020-05-17", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21", "2020-05-22", "2020-05-23", "2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", "2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29", "2020-05-30", "2020-05-31" ]



const getDay = dateString => {
  const d = new Date(dateString);
  const dayName = d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });
  const weekend = d.getDay() === 0 || d.getDay() === 6;
  const pubHol = publicHolidays.includes(dateString);
  let className = weekend ? "green" : "white"; // class is a reserved word
  if (pubHol) className = "blue";
  return { dayName, className };
};

const cells = daysNumber.map((dateString, index) => {
  const dateObj = getDay(dateString)
  return `<td align="right" class="${dateObj.className}" key="mi-${index}">${dateObj.dayName}</td>`
});
document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML=cells.join("");
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black }
.white { color:orange }
.green { color:green }
.blue { color:blue }
```

```html
<table><tr id="cal"></tr></table>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Can I use more conditions? Like if Saturday and Sunday and any other day from PublicHolidays do it blue color. And if Saturday and Sunday from daysNumber do green and all other stay white?

Comment: I ran your code but problem is that it only makes blue to sat and sun while other days stay white. I mean I have 3 `"2020-05-02","2020-05-06","2020-05-21"` and they should turn blue. If there is saturday and sunday included in them they should have to be blue but rest of sat sun would stay green and other all boxes would stay white. Did you get it? So all dates from publicholiday will be blue but if there is saturday and sunday included in them they will also be blue. Rest of all sat sun from daysNumber will be green and other all will be white.

Comment: I meant to say, So all dates from publicholiday will be blue but if there is saturday and sunday included in them they will also be blue. Rest of all sat sun from daysNumber will be green and remaining all will be white. That's my main requuirement here. Hopefully you will get it :)

Comment: Yes, all weekends are now green unless they are also a pubhol, then they are blue. As you asked. So Sat May 2nd is blue and Sun 3rd is green

Comment: Yes that right. But see `,"2020-05-06","2020-05-21"` they both should have to blue color as well.

Comment: Basically `,"2020-05-06","2020-05-21"` if they are not blue too client will not be able to see that it was public holiday schedule on this day. Our main goal is to give preference to Sat Sun blue color over green sat sun. Did you get me?

Comment: Its mean that Sat Sun are greens but if public holiday is scheduled on Sat Sun we will make blue but we also need to set blue to other days on which public holiday is scheduled. I think now I made that clear properly.

Comment: hahaha :) Thanks for your compliment. Made my day at 11:30PM :D. Stay blessed Sir. Thanks again.

Comment: sorry to bother you again here but there is little change needed in the script. Client wants to have week show based on German calendar. So, in May, 19th week is starting from Monday to Sunday which is showing fine in our country but in germany it should be like, 04 may to 10 may ( 19th Week - Monday to Sunday ). Can we add germany based timezone in your current code? So when client will see, it will load like I explained you above. Its fine for our country as he says in germany week start from monday to sunday but on client's end on UI with current code, it showing like Sun to Sat

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you need. What is the expected output? I am only rendering what you gave me

Comment: So my client says, in germany week 19 starts from Monday to Sunday but when he access the website from his country ( germany ), it shows him week number 19 starting from Sunday to Saturday. I think we need to define timezone ( germany ) in our code so that whenever he will access website from germany the week number will start to work as per his expectations.

Comment: I am missing the part where you define a week. There are no week numbers in the code

Comment: So I went to your other questions. Are you not commenting on the wrong question?